# cannot install node modules and getting an error in Mac M1

Tags: node.js, reactjs, macos, npm, apple-m1

I'm trying to npm i in my new Mac M1 and I get the below error. Appreciate if anyone can have a look and provide a solution.

I tried several solutions, but I ended up getting the same error.

```
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/pinpoint@2.0.0: Moved to 'npm install @sideway/pinpoint'
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /Users/lsdinduruwage/Documents/ZP-Projects/ZIP_Portal_V2/node_modules/bufferutil
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c node-gyp-build
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@3.8.0
npm ERR! gyp info using node@16.13.0 | darwin | arm64
npm ERR! gyp http GET https://nodejs.org/download/release/v16.13.0/node-v16.13.0-headers.tar.gz
npm ERR! (node:23716) Warning: Setting the NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED environment variable to '0' makes TLS

connections and HTTPS requests insecure by disabling certificate verification.

npm ERR! (Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
npm ERR! gyp http 200 https://nodejs.org/download/release/v16.13.0/node-v16.13.0-headers.tar.gz
npm ERR! gyp WARN install got an error, rolling back install
npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error 
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: aborted
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at connResetException (node:internal/errors:691:14)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at TLSSocket.socketCloseListener (node:_http_client:407:19)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:402:35)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at node:net:687:12
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at TCP.done (node:_tls_wrap:580:7)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Darwin 22.2.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "/Users/lsdinduruwage/.nvm/versions/node/v16.13.0/bin/node" "/Users/lsdinduruwage/Documents/ZP-Projects/ZIP_Portal_V2/node_modules/.bin/node-gyp" "rebuild"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd /Users/lsdinduruwage/Documents/ZP-Projects/ZIP_Portal_V2/node_modules/bufferutil
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v16.13.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/lsdinduruwage/.npm/_logs

/2023-01-04T06_09_45_617Z-debug.log
```

I tried `npm i --force` as well. I get the same error.

Comment: Can you try to remove the `node_modules` folder and the `package-lock.json` file and run `npm install` again?

Answer (score 1):

`npm cache clean --force`

or

`npm cache clean`

if it doesn't work then manually search the **cache folder** delete from **`~/.npm`** . *Maximum times it's done by `npm cache clean` It's work perfectly.*

> After that run

`npm cache verify`

> After that install

`npm install npm@latest -g`

Answer (score -1):

My problem was caused due to python version 3.*. Downgraded to 2.7* and it works, after re-installing node-gyp on the version nodejs (using nvm).

Comment: this may not be a good solution as [python 2 is sunsetted](https://www.python.org/doc/sunset-python-2/) in 2020